# How to retrieve text of an element without tag using following child in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have an element that is sibling to another element who is without an enclosing tag. I'm trying to target this second element, so I can retrieve its text. I can do this from the console using `div[4]/h5/following-sibling::text()[1]` so the format `parent/sibling/following-sibling::text()[1]`. But the text() part breaks Selenium despite working fine on the inspector tool. Not sure how to proceed other than getting the whole parent div and breaking its String text such as

```
String dateString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-dialog-container/ims-presenting-complaint-create/ims-presenting-complaint-details/div/div[3]/div[4]")).getText().split("\\n")[1];
```

But feel there may be a better way to get the sibling element without doing this?

[image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text()` returns TextNode, Selenium doesn't support it. It works in the devtools because it executes JQuery. The workaround you mentioned is the way to go, or you can locate the div and `<h5>` and remove the child text from the complete text

```
WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-dialog-container/ims-presenting-complaint-create/ims-presenting-complaint-details/div/div[3]/div[4]"));
String allText = parentElement.getText();
String childText = parentElement.findElement(By.xpath("./h5"));
String dateString = allText.replace(childText, "");
```

Or you can use JS

```
String dateString = driver.executeScript("return document.evaluate('div[4]/h5/following-sibling::text()[1]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.textContent;");
```